# overloading multiple operators in one function

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

is it possible to overload multiple operators in one operator overload?

I want to do something like this:

```cpp
template<operator O>
MyClass operator<O>(const MyClass & other) {
return this.x <O> other.x;
}
```

where x is an int attribute of the class.

so that itll be possible to overload all of the int operators at once, meaning I could with one function, overload +, -, *, / etc. insted of copy pasting a code a milion times and just changing one line.

in my specific example I have a struct Point which contains two integers, and another struct called Pointf which contains two floats, and I want to be able to add, subtruct, multiply and devide them with each other or with an int value, currently Im doing that with dozen of functions, but I would like to do it with just a few functions, I would like to overwrite the +=, -=, *- and /= as well.

Comment: CRTP might avoid some repetition from one class to the other, but nothing to use "automatic" projection for operator.

Comment: you can use pre processor macro concatenation for combining `operator` and `op`.

Comment: Short answer:  no.     Comparison operators (since C++20) are a special case, in which there is support for the spaceship operator, and automatic generation in some particular cases.    But there is not any implicit generation of other math operators.    A workaround is to use a macro, where the macro expansion explicitly defines a set of operators (e.g. `operator+()`, `operator+=()`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't overload multiple operators in one operator overload. You could however make a class template to use for all your `Point`s:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Point_impl {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    template <typename U>
    friend class Point_impl;

    Point_impl() : x_{}, y_{} {}            // default
    Point_impl(T x, T y) : x_{x}, y_{y} {}  // conversion

    // create one Point_impl<T> from a Point_impl<U> 
    template<typename U>
    Point_impl(const Point_impl<U>& rhs) :
        x_{static_cast<T>(rhs.x_)},
        y_{static_cast<T>(rhs.y_)}
    {}

    T get_x() const { return x_; }
    T get_y() const { return y_; }

    // add a Point_impl<U> to *this
    template<typename U>
    Point_impl<T>& operator+=(const Point_impl<U>& rhs) {
        x_ += static_cast<U>(rhs.x_);
        y_ += static_cast<U>(rhs.y_);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    Point_impl<T>& operator-=(const Point_impl<U>& rhs) {
        x_ -= static_cast<U>(rhs.x_);
        y_ -= static_cast<U>(rhs.y_);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    Point_impl<T>& operator*=(const Point_impl<U>& rhs) {
        x_ *= static_cast<U>(rhs.x_);
        y_ *= static_cast<U>(rhs.y_);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    Point_impl<T>& operator/=(const Point_impl<U>& rhs) {
        x_ /= static_cast<U>(rhs.x_);
        y_ /= static_cast<U>(rhs.y_);
        return *this;
    }

    // for printing a point:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point_impl<T>& p) {
        return os << '(' << p.x_ << ',' << p.y_ << ')';
    }

private:
    T x_, y_;
};
```

The free functions operating with different underlying types could then be done like this:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
auto operator+(const Point_impl<L>& lhs, const Point_impl<R>& rhs) {
    // return the properly promoted Point_impl type deduced from if the
    // underlying types were added
    Point_impl<decltype(lhs.get_x() + rhs.get_x())> rv = lhs;
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<typename L, typename R>
auto operator-(const Point_impl<L>& lhs, const Point_impl<R>& rhs) {
    Point_impl<decltype(lhs.get_x() - rhs.get_x())> rv = lhs;
    rv -= rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<typename L, typename R>
auto operator*(const Point_impl<L>& lhs, const Point_impl<R>& rhs) {
    Point_impl<decltype(lhs.get_x() * rhs.get_x())> rv = lhs;
    rv *= rhs;
    return rv;
}

template<typename L, typename R>
auto operator/(const Point_impl<L>& lhs, const Point_impl<R>& rhs) {
    Point_impl<decltype(lhs.get_x() / rhs.get_x())> rv = lhs;
    rv /= rhs;
    return rv;
}
```

And you could also add aliases for convenience:

```
using Point = Point_impl<int>;
using Pointl = Point_impl<long>;
using Pointf = Point_impl<float>;
using Pointd = Point_impl<double>;
using Pointld = Point_impl<long double>;
```

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    Point x(1,2);             // Point_impl<int>
    Pointf y(3.141f,6.282f);  // Point_impl<float>
    auto z = x + y;           // int + float => Point_impl<float>

    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(z), Pointf>::value << '\n';  // prints 1
    std::cout << z << '\n';                                         // (4.141,8.282)
}
```